# Is there a way to use Visual Studio's Klocwork Plugin without solution?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, cmake, klocwork

I've installed the Klocwork Plugin for Visual Studio. I am using a CMake project and therefore I do not have a Visual Studio file (.sln).  I cannot modify the "solution properties" in the klocwork plugin and I want to know if it is possible to use the plugin. I am using VS2017.

I expect to see real time analysis of Klocwork on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please let me know if you can build your project in Visual Studio?.

Klocwork need to watch your build to create the meta data for analysis.

if you are using CMake for command line build and using any editor (Notepad, Wordpad, Notepadd++, vi, VIM, etc..,) to edit the code, then you can use Klocwork Desktop for real time analysis. Here is the documentation from Klocwork, https://docs.roguewave.com/en/klocwork/current/gettingstartedwithklocworkdesktopforcc#concept800